# How do I generate an array in D?

Tags: arrays, d

I have this c++11 code:

```
auto gen = []() -> double { /* do stuff */ };
std::generate(myArray.begin(), myArray.end(), gen);
```

How would I do the same with D's array?  `std.algorithm.fill` doesn't take a function object, and I don't know how to pass a function to `recurrence`.

Comment: You want to fill existing array with data in-place?

Comment: @Nekuromento Yes. generating a new array would work too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a version that seems to work:

```
import std.algorithm, std.array, std.range, std.stdio;

void main() {
  writefln("%s", __VERSION__);
  int i;
  auto dg = delegate float(int) { return i++; };
  float[] res = array(map!dg(iota(0, 10)));
  float[] res2 = new float[10];
  fill(res2, map!dg(iota(0, res2.length)));
  writefln("meep");
  writefln("%s", res);
  writefln("%s", res2);
}
```

[edit] Added fill-based version (res2).

I tested it in Ideone (http://www.ideone.com/DFK5A) but it crashes .. a [friend](https://stackoverflow.com/users/61/bernard) with a current version of DMD says it works though, so I assume Ideone's DMD is just outdated by about ten to twenty versions.

Comment: ideone will tell you what version of the compiler that it's using when you run your code on it. It's currently using dmd 2.042. The current version of dmd is 2.055, so that's 13 versions behind. So, I wouldn't trust ideone for much of anything with regards to D code at this point. There's plenty of stuff which will work, but too much has changed since 2.042 for it to be a very good test for compilability or behavior.

Comment: Oh, didn't see that - thus the writefln("%s", \_\_VERSION\_\_) at the top. :)

Comment: Sorry, but not quite.  The array is supposed to hold floats, and `iota` doesn't work with floats (for me with 2.055 I get `Internal error: ../ztc/cg87.c 202`).

Comment: I don't know why you get that. Try a slightly older version.

The array is supposed to hold floats, but you're missing the fact that we're using iota to map an _int range_ onto a float-producing function. So it all works out. (Note that my arrays are typed as float[]. Note further that I have confirmation that this works. )

Answer (score -1):

You could do something like

```
auto arr = {/* generate an array and return that array */}();
```

If it's assigned to a global it should be evaluated at compile-time.

You can also use string mixins to generate code for an array literal.

Comment: Sorry, but that has almost nothing to do with what he wanted.

Comment: Why? He said generating a new array is also ok.

Comment: What he's doing is mapping a range onto a function in order to fill in or produce an array. With what you're doing, the function is basically superfluous.